# Swift constraints break frame width and height

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to define a circular button centered slightly above the bottom of the screen:

```
let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
let diameter: Double = 64

button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

button.setTitle("Upvote", for: [])
button.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: diameter, height: diameter)
button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.93, green:0, blue:0.55, alpha:1)
button.layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(diameter / 2)

view.addConstraints([
  createConstraint(button, .centerX, .equal, view, .centerX),
  createConstraint(button, .bottom, .equal, view, .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: -100),
])

button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleUpvoteButtonTap), for: .touchUpInside)

view.addSubview(button)
```

`createConstraint` is just a shorthand wrapper for `NSLayoutConstraint`

```
func createConstraint(_ item: Any, _ attribute: NSLayoutAttribute, _ relation: NSLayoutRelation, _ toItem: Any, _ toAttribute: NSLayoutAttribute, multiplier: Double = 1, constant: Double = 0) -> NSLayoutConstraint {
  return NSLayoutConstraint(
    item: item,
    attribute: attribute,
    relatedBy: relation,
    toItem: toItem,
    attribute: toAttribute,
    multiplier: CGFloat(multiplier),
    constant: CGFloat(constant)
  )
}
```

The problem I'm having is the the button isn't being rendered with the width/height `diameter` (it appears to try to match the dimensions of its title text). If I remove the `addConstraints` call, the button looks fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've only set positioning constraints, so the size will be determined by the button's `intrinsicContentSize` which will be determined in your case by the button's title. If you want it to have specific size, set sizing constraints. For example:

```
button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: diameter).isActive = true
button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: diameter).isActive = true
```

As soon as you set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` all frame-based positioning and sizing will be ignored.